# Crear un usuario con permisos administrativos sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure, transact-sql

Tengo un servicio SQL Server en Microsoft Azure.
Requiero crear un usuario con rol "sysadmin":

He creado  el login desde SSMS, conectándome al servidor con las credenciales de server admin proporcionadas por azure

```
CREATE LOGIN RSUADMIN WITH PASSWORD = 'XXXX'
GO
```

E intenté asignarle un rol:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [RSUADMIN] FOR LOGIN [RSUADMIN]
    use master
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N'sysadmin', N'RSUADMIN'
END;
GO
```

pero me muestra el siguiente error:

**Cannot alter the role 'db_owner', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion de SQL server, requiere que ejecutes la instruccion conectandose al servidor con una cuenta de tipo `db_securityadmin` o `db_owner`.

En otras palabras, no puedes asignar un rol administrativo con una cuenta no administrativa. Cualquiera se podria agregar a si mismo como admin, escalar permisos y acceder a recursos privilegiados.

> Permisos
>
> Para agregar miembros a los roles flexibles de la base de
> datos, se debe cumplir una de las condiciones siguientes:
>
> - Pertenencia al rol fijo de base de datos db_securityadmin o db_owner.
> - Se debe pertenecer al rol propietario del rol.
> - El permiso ALTER any role o el
>   permiso ALTER en el rol.
>
> Para poder agregar miembros a los roles fijos
> de base de datos es necesario pertenecer al rol fijo de base de datos
> db_owner.